# parsing XML with PHP need to display the embedded HTML as markup

Tags: php, xml, parsing, atom-feed

I'm writing a simple atom XML parser with PHP

I have trouble displaying the proper content inside the `<content>` tag if there is additional HTML tag within.

Ex. If I want to parse the following XML

```
 <entry> 
       <title>Test entry #3</title> 
       <id>http://example.org/article3</id> 
       <updated>2006-10-03T13:14:34Z</updated> 
       <link href="http://example.org/article3" /> 
       <content type="xhtml" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
         <xhtml:div>This is also <xhtml:em>very</xhtml:em> exciting. &amp; <xhtml:img src="http://www.w3.org/y" alt=":-)" /></xhtml:div> 
       </content> 
     </entry>
```

my code will not display anything inside the `<content>` tag. What method do I use to bypass and embed all the text side the `<content>` to display as proper HTML ?

**Update**: I used `htmlspecialchars` method to pass everything inside the `$content` but that doesn't seems to get the job done.

I guess I need to make this more clear, my goal is to pass those `<xhtml:div>` as markup so the browser will display it properly

Comment: Which XML parser are you using: DOMDocument, SimpleXML, XMLReader, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

```
<![CDATA[<p>HTML goes here</p>]]!>
```